# Index of vector iterator

Tags: c++

So I have a basic vector iterator, which looks like:

```
for (std::vector<string>::iterator i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
{
    // Need the index here
}
```

I've tried using `&i` but that just returns true. I need to return the index. Would I need to create my own integer?

Comment: What do you mean by *`// Need the ID here`*? What is an *ID*, what is it that you want ID-ed? [BTW, `&i` does not return `true`, although it might seem so if you attempt to print it with `std::cout`...]

Comment: `iterator`s don't have "IDs"  What are you **really** trying to do?

Comment: I meant index, sorry. I have no idea why I used ID's to describe it. Already answered. Thanks though.

Comment: `std::distance(vec.begin(), i);`

Comment: if you need index, why you doun't use smth like this `for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i){ /*stuff with vec[i]*/}`

Comment: it's convential to use `it` for iterators, and `i` for indices. Your co-workers will thank you for using that convention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by 'ID' you mean index, use

```
i - vec.begin()
```