# C++ Iterators: How to find the index for a heapsort

Tags: c++, iterator, heap

Let's say I have a vector to sort:

```
std::vector v{9, 8, 0, 2, 7, 3, 2, 1}
```

Suppose I want to start sorting at the third element (index 2) until the end, and so I have an iterator pointing to 0 for begin and past 1 for end. If I use indices and pass into a function the index of the current element, to find the left child of "0" I would use 2*index+1.

Let "iter" be the iterator pointing to 0, at index 2. The following:

```
iter+1
```

would move the iterator so that *iter will now equal 2. However, I can't move the iterator to the left child by:

```
2*iter+1
```

How can I work around this and move the iterator to the right position? Is there a way to find the index of the iterator?

Comment: Is it me or did we get the same question earlier?

Comment: @EdHeal: You remember correctly. [This is a duplicate.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341220/index-of-vector-iterator) It seems like very few people use SO search before posting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::distance`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/). For example:

```
auto index = std::distance(v.begin(), iter);
```

Quoting:

> If it is a random-access iterator, the function uses operator- to calculate this. Otherwise, the function uses the increase operator (operator++) repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks! I did end up using operator-.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector`'s iterator is a random access iterator, so the index of the iterator `itr` is  `itr - vec.begin()`